# String validations c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a 9 character string I am trying to provide multiple checks on.  I want to first check if the first 1 - 7 characters are numbers and then say for example the first 3 characters are numbers how would I check the 5th character for a letter range of G through T.

I am using c# and have tried this so far...

```
string checkString = "123H56789";
Regex charactorSet = new Regex("[G-T]");
Match matchSetOne = charactorSetOne.Match(checkString, 3);

if (Char.IsNumber(checkString[0]) && Char.IsNumber(checkString[1]) && Char.IsNumber(checkString[2]))
            {
                if (matchSetOne.Success)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("3th char is a letter");
                }
            }
```

But am not sure if this is the best way to handle the validations.

UPDATE:
The digits can be 0 - 9, but can concatenate from one number to seven. Like this "12345T789" or "1R3456789" etc.

Comment: The 5th character cannot be a letter since *the first 1 - 7 characters are numbers*. Also, `123H5678` has 8 symbols. Please check your requirements. Finally, your error message implies the 3rd character must be a digit (*Console.WriteLine("3th char is a letter")*) while a 4th one is a letter in your code example.

Comment: Your string length is 8 characters. Please explain the rule properly.

Comment: Sounds like a regular expression might be the way to go, but I can't write one for you since your question is extremely self-contradictory. Please provide a detailed list of valid and invalid strings, with explanation of why each is valid or invalid.

Comment: I have a string that is 9 characters. The first 7 characters can range from 1 to 7 numbers, but if say the 4th character is a letter I need to validate that that character is in a range of G though T.  Make better sense?

Comment: Try `@"^\d{3}[\dG-T]\d{5}$"`? Or you mean digits from `1` to `7`: `@"^[1-7]{3}[1-7G-T][1-7]{3}\d{2}$"`? (where the last two digits can be any digits from `0` to `9`). Still, the end pattern is unclear. Or can the last characters be any? Then use `.{2}` instead of `\d{2}`.

Comment: The digits can be 0 - 9, but can concatenate from one number to seven. Like this "12345T789" or "1R3456789" etc.

Comment: Please add these explanations to the question.

Comment: Hm, maybe you need something like `^1234[6G-T]789$`?

Comment: Problem with that example is the numbers would always be in different positions

Answer (score 0):

It'a easy with LINQ:

- check if the first 1 - 7 characters are numbers :

  ```
  var condition1 = input.Take(7).All(c => Char.IsDigit(c));
  ```
- check the 5th character for a letter range of G through T

  ```
  var condition2 = input.ElementAt(4) >= 'G' &&  input.ElementAt(4) <= 'T';
  ```

As it is, both conditions can't be true at the same time (if the first 7 chars are digits, then the 5th char can't be a letter).

Comment: I know there would be multiple combinations, could I use a substring method or some kind of char.isnumber check on range? Would I have to use a combination of regex and conditional statements?

Comment: You can use `String.Substring` as well, to combine multiple conditions just use `&&`